# Cant find Element on this website : Unable to locate element: //button[@type='save'][text()='Accept All']

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

// i am trying to find an element on a page which would accept cookies.

Error message: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //button[@type='save'][text()='Accept All']

```
package com.CookiesTest.webdriver;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Cookie;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionId;

public class CookiesExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception

    {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Habib\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("https://demo.guru99.com/v4/index.php");//load url
        //Thread.sleep(3000);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);//wait for element

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='save'][text()='Accept All']")).click();//find element



    }


}
```

Comment: I don't find the cookies banner visiting `https://demo.guru99.com/v4/index.php` Update the question with the relevant HTML of the element.

Comment: @habs not show accept button on the website you where guven

Answer (score 0):

You will get this exception only when,

1. The object is not available in the application
2. The locator is incorrect

Comment: i could not find the xpath for that cookie element, if you run the code the browser lods, and then the cookies notification shows, i have tried looking for the elements with xpath but could not find it.   can you try and find the element with a locator and run the code